# Return list of strings containing the list of files in a directory in C

Tags: c

There are many examples on this site of printing out the list of files in a directory using C on this site. However, I haven't been able to find a way to return a list of strings (`char ***` maybe?) such that:

```
some_variable_type list;
listdir("~/test_folder",list); //this is the function I need
for() //each item in list
{
    printf("This is a file in the folder: %s\n", item);
    do_thing_on_file(item);
}
```

Is it even possible to make this work without knowing how many files are in the folder beforehand? For the sake of completeness, please help me write not just `listdir()` but also the variables I need to setup beforehand to call it.

**Edit regarding duplicate**: As I mentioned above, I do not believe the linked question as duplicate does not answer my question, because the solutions (save for one) all print a list of strings or involve C++ or use a variable to guess the number of files in the directory beforehand, and that one solution does not provide the setup for the variables outside the function needed to call it.

When run, the code would simply print the name of each file in a folder, and also execute another function on each file (that is out of the scope of this question). The point is that I need to access the names of the files in the folder outside of the scope of the `listdir()` function, and simply printing them to stdout like the answers in the duplicate question isn't good enough.

Comment: I have seen that snippet marked as duplicate and have explained in my question why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Could you provide some example output that you would like?  That might help to clarify.

Comment: in C++ you don't have to know the size beforehand using `std::vector<string>`. In C you have to implement a dynamic reallocation system to increase list size depending on directory contents.

Comment: Could you post an answer demonstrating how? Also, I've provided enough clarification for the question to not be considered a duplicate, no?